# imap_open виснет

Tags: php, imap

В php новичок, сильно не пинайте плиз.
Виснет imap_open причем с концами, пока не убьешь процесс. Погуглил, народ действительно жалуется. Решения не нашел. Указал

```
imap_timeout(IMAP_READTIMEOUT, 60);
```

не помогает, куда копать?
Любые мысли..
Помогите пожалуйста, очень надо.

Comment: Вопрос к сожалению не новичка. Ловил эту проблему виснет на ожидании сети и игнорирует все таймауты `imap_timeout`. backtrace от gdb подтверждает, что проблема в библиотеке и уводит в глубины С кода.  Возможно проблема специфична только для SSL https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61846 Но от этого не легче, т.к. большинство imap серверов теперь только с шифрованием работают. Я в итоге запускаю скрипт через `timeout 15m php imapreader.php`

Comment: @Мелкий спасибо за ответ, уточните что это за скрипт `timeout 15m php imapreader.php`

Comment: `timeout` - команда из coreutils, а потому обычно есть в наличии. Запускает и по прошествии указанного времени убивает указанную команду. 15m - 15 минут соответственно. То есть скрипт будет убит по прошествии 15 минут чем бы тот не занимался и чего не ждал.

Comment: @Мелкий ну у меня нет coreutils, пробовал `set_time_limit();` ставить тоже не помогает. В итоге сейчас поставил zend-mail, сижу переписываю.